# Convert String Datatype Column to MapType in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as shown below. I want to convert the last column Trandata from String Type to MapType. The output should look something similar I have shown in 2nd table.

I have written udf but it takes string and converts to Maptype, I'm struggle to get similar output with sql.row as input. :(

```
def stringToMap(value: String): Map[String, String] = {
  var valMap = collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
  val values = value.split(",")
  for (i <- values) {
    valMap = valMap + (i.split("=")(0) -> i.split("=")(1))
  }
  return valMap
}


+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MESSAGEID     |CATEGORY|TRANDATA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|03010         |A       |threadID=123sada,ProcType=InfraLogging,TxnID=4mjx8wfogf
|03011         |A       |threadID=xmjxe2j0jz,ProcType=InfraLogging,TxnID=4mjxe2j0tf
|09941         |D       |compTxnID=xmawdew0tf,to=ABCD,threadID=4mjxe2j0jz,ProcType=InfraLogging
|00994         |D       |compTxnID=xmjxe2j0tf,to=XYZA,threadID=34jxasde0jz,ProcType=InfraLogging
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table2: Expceted output - 3rd col to be MapType

```
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MESSAGEID     |CATEGORY|TRANDATA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|03010         |A       |Map(threadID -> 123sada,ProcType -> InfraLogging,TxnID -> 4mjx8wfogf)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+ you can [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#split(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) the string into key value pairs, then use [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) to separate keys and values into two array columns and then use [map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#map_from_arrays) to create the final map.

```scala
df.withColumn("entry", split('TRANDATA, ","))
  .withColumn("key", expr("transform(entry, x -> split(x, '=')[0])"))
  .withColumn("value", expr("transform(entry, x -> split(x, '=')[1])"))
  .withColumn("map", map_from_arrays('key, 'value))
  .drop("entry", "key", "value", "TRANDATA")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MESSAGEID|CATEGORY|map                                                                                     |
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|03010    |A       |[threadID -> 123sada, ProcType -> InfraLogging, TxnID -> 4mjx8wfogf]                    |
|03011    |A       |[threadID -> xmjxe2j0jz, ProcType -> InfraLogging, TxnID -> 4mjxe2j0tf]                 |
|09941    |D       |[compTxnID -> xmawdew0tf, to -> ABCD, threadID -> 4mjxe2j0jz, ProcType -> InfraLogging] |
|00994    |D       |[compTxnID -> xmjxe2j0tf, to -> XYZA, threadID -> 34jxasde0jz, ProcType -> InfraLogging]|
+---------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much Werner. Spark 2.4+ contains lot more options, it's good my production servers are upgraded to 2.4.x version, So above code should work fine.